# Send json data to nodejs server

Tags: json, node.js

I have a problem sending json data to my node server

I tried

```
var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://33.33.33.15/user/signin',
        headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
        data: {test:"test"}
 };
```

when I `console.log()` req.body y have

```
{ '{"test":"test"}': '' }
```

When I try with

```
var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://33.33.33.15/user/signin',
        headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
        data: 'test=test'
 };
```

I have a good result on the server

I set the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded to allow the cross domain

On the server I have

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send it as JSON, then you may consider doing so:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://33.33.33.15/user/signin',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ test: 'test' })
};
```