# How can I return a value from a Javascript file to a Node.js so I can write to a file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a Javascript file which reads the inputs of a form and puts it into a JSON string. I want to create a file and write the JSON string to the file. I know how to write to files using Node but I am wanting to know how I can pass the string to my server.js file.

Can anyone help?

Javascript file (script.js)

```
(function() {
function toJSONString( form ) {
    var obj = {};
    var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input, select, textarea" );
    var store = elements[0];
    var configValue = store.value;
    for( var i = 1; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var name = element.name;
        var value = element.value;
        if( name ) {
            obj[ name ] = value;
        }
    }
    console.log(configValue);
    return JSON.stringify({ [configValue] : [ obj ]  } );
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var form = document.getElementById( "test" );
    var output = document.getElementById( "output" );
    var fs = require('fs');
    form.addEventListener( "submit", function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var json = toJSONString( this );
        output.innerHTML = json;
    }, false);

});

})();
```

Node.js file (server.js):

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var script = require('./public/script.js');

const app = express()
.get('/', function (req, res) {res.sendFile(INDEX)})
.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const io = socketIO(app);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send json data to nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918098/send-json-data-to-nodejs-server)

Comment: On top of @DanO answer, [you can use `fs` to write to a file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you are handling the stringification of your form on the client-side and want to pass it to your NodeJS server. To do that, you have to send a HTTP POST request to your server.

That means :

1. Create a server side POST route that parses your JSON and write it into a file.
2. On client side, after stringifying the JSON, send the POST request to the route you just created, To do that you can use the built-it javascript `fetch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Hope that answers your question!